# Best Way to Return a Class in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a C++ vector class for a project and I'm having a hard time making a decision about how best to write some of the methods. Before I start I will say that the class has a good copy constructor and assignment operator (this will be relevant in a sec). The class has a set of static methods that return vectors when I want to make sure that neither parameter is altered, they have signatures like:

```
Vector* Vector::subtract(const Vector* v, const Vector* u)
{
    double outX = v->myX - u->myX;
    double outY = v->myY - u->myY;
    double outZ = v->myZ - u->myZ;

    return new Vector(outX, outY, outZ);
}
```

The problem I am having is that I don't want to return pointers if I can help it. So instead I did some testing and realized that if I just say

```
return Vector(outX, outY, outZ)
```

and then assign the result like

```
Vector foo = Vector::subtract(bar, temp)
```

it will create a copy and work fine. Here's where my question lies: I just called the constructor twice (essentially) is there a way to get around that? Secondly, if I use this method as a argument to another method like

```
foo.multiply(&Vector::subtract(foo, bar), 5)
```

will it still create a copy or did I just pass the pointer that has gone out of scope in the Vector::subtract method?

More generally, what is the best (or at least is there a better) way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just called the constructor twice (essentially) is there a way to
>   get around that?

Have you ever heard of [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)? There is nothing you have to do. The compiler will most likely eliminate the copy for you. Now, if you use C++11 and the `Vector` class manages a resource, you could declare a move constructor also, so that the returned value is moved just in case the compiler decides it cannot perform RVO. However, it looks like the class only holds 3 values, if that is the case, copying is going to be as efficient as moving.

> &Vector::subtract(foo, bar)

What is the `&` for? Was that a mistake? Also, the member function is not declared `static` so the syntax is wrong. Anyways, assuming `subtract` returns a copy, it will return a copy and pass that to the `multiply` function as an argument.

Also, on another note, `Vector* Vector::subtract(const Vector* v, const Vector* u)`
 would be better as `Vector* Vector::subtract(const Vector& v, const Vector& u)`, this makes the syntax cleaner when you pass arguments to subtract, etc.

So changing your code, it would look something like the following:

```
Vector Vector::subtract(const Vector& v, const Vector& u)
{
    return Vector(v.myX - u.myX, v.myY - u.myY, v.myZ - u.myZ);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, the multiply method (right now) takes a pointer, so I would need to pass the address of the object returned by subtract (there is a static subtract method also, again sorry about being ambiguous). In that case it would still be the address of the copy though?

Comment: A move constructor won't help much in a type that seems to just hold 3 values (i.e. there is no *resource* to move)

Comment: @Pat: Right, that is very dangerous, the returned copy is a temporary, so that pointer is pointing at invalid memory. Change the `multiply` to take a const reference instead.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Good point, I clarified that in my answer.

Comment: @JesseGood: It is not legal to take the address of a temporary, so it would not be *dangerous*, but rather it won't compile.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thanks for reminding me. IIRC older versions of [gcc](http://ideone.com/mh8SB) and MSVC allowed it though.

Answer (score 2):

Returning pointers/references to dynamically allocated objects is never the way to go. And obvious example would be if your function is called recursively, who is responsible for de-allocating that memory?

I've read from a book (by Scott Meyers, it was Effective C++ Item #21) that the only safe way to do it was to return the object itself. What you could do is, IIRC, facilitate the compilers job at eliminating these objects that are essentially temporare (returned from one function to be fed to another without every being assigned to another) and one of those ways was to make it anonymous (aka as the Return Value Optimization, thanks to In silico for reminding me). Like so

```
return Vector(outX, outY, outZ);
```

as opposed to:

```
Vector v(outX, outY, outZ);
return v;
```

So my proposed signature for your subtract method comes down to:

```
Vector Vector::subtract(const Vector& v, const Vector& u)
```

Comment: It doesn't detract from your point, but compilers aren't that stupid when it comes to RVO -- any intelligent compiler is going to use RVO in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers these days will implement what is called Return Value Optimization (RVO) to combat this problem. You're right that you shouldn't return pointers unless it's really necessary. That being said, you should probably be using references. All in all, if I was going to write this method, this is how I'd write it:

```
Vector Vector::subtract(const Vector& v, const Vector& u)
{
    return Vector(v.myX - u.myX, v.myY - u.myY, v.myZ - u.myZ);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid pointers as much as possible, not only in the return type but also in arguments to functions. Prefer references whenever possible, use pointers when you must.

If you change your functions to take the arguments by reference and return by value. Consider overloading operators when it makes sense in the domain (which I believe is the case here):

```
class Vector { ... };
Vector operator+( Vector const& lhs, Vector const& rhs ) {
   return Vector( lhs.x+rhs.x, lhs.y+rhs.y, lhs.z+rhs.y );
}
Vector operator*( Vector const& lhs, Vector const& rhs ) { ... }
```

Then you can chain operations at will:

```
Vector a(...), b(...);
Vector c = (a + b) * c;
```

Comment: I actually was planning on doing just that at some point. Thanks!

Comment: @Pat: Note that while addition and subtraction have a clear meaning, you might want to provide a named function for multiplication to make it clear whether it is the dot product or the cross-product

Comment: Multiplication was actually memberwise scaling by a scalar, but yea I agree a name change would be a good idea.

Comment: @Pat: Memberwise scaling is kind of understood by everyone as to what is expected. There is no problem in having that as an operator.